# Coerce a ByteArrayInputStream to InputStream

Tags: java, jruby, bytearrayinputstream

I have some code that does:

```
content = Java::byte[s].new
f = tar.read(content, 0, s)
content_stream = ByteArrayInputStream.new(content)
```

So far, so good

But when I try to use a method that only takes an InputStream, like so:

```
metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(content_stream)
```

I get the following exception:

```
NameError: no method 'readMetadata' for arguments (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream) on Java::ComDrewImaging::ImageMetadataReader
```

I've tried using `content_stream.to_java(java.io.InputStream)` and that still generates the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single-argument readMetadata() takes a file; there is a two-argument that takes a *Buffered*InputStream and a boolean.  You could wrap your ByteArrayInputStream in a BufferedInputStream and decide whether you want to 'waitForBytes', whatever that means...

Comment: The BufferedInputStream was the answer! I thought I was going crazy, but I was just looking at the wrong version of ImageMetadataReader.java - from master, not 2.6.4, which is the version I'm actually using. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because readMetadata has 2 signatures, one with one argument: a java.io.File and a second which you try to use that takes 2 arguments a ByteArrayInputStream and a boolean. Try to replace your code with `ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(content_stream, false)`

Comment: That gets me `NameError: no method 'readMetadata' for arguments (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream,org.jruby.RubyBoolean.False) on Java::ComDrewImaging::ImageMetadataReader`